# How to load YouTube videos inline search when scrolled down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I am working on YouTube inline search. I have a code in which I can only update 50 videos in my page. I want to increase this number to infinite as it should be like infinite scrolling. As you can see that after 50 videos are loaded, bottom of the page there is link named `Load Next`. I don't need this links. What I need is, when I scroll down if necessary a loader should be visible in the list and in the meanwhile this videos list gets loaded. Any suggestions please.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/madhu72kumar/B5RMg/1/)**

```
<form onsubmit="ytEmbed.init({'block':'youtubeDivSearch','type':'search','q':document.getElementById('ytSearchField').value,'results': 50,'order':'most_relevance'}); return false;">
  <input  type="text" id="ytSearchField">  <input type="submit" value="  Search  ">
</form>
<div id="youtubeDivSearch"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to trigger the **loadNext** function of ytEmbed once you reach the bottom of the #youtubeDivSearch container. You could trigger this with an infinate scroller plugin ([jscroll.com](http://jscroll.com/) for example)

However, you may need to manually remove the auto insertion of "load next" by the ytEmbed script